# How to give relative path?

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I want to be in folder C:\EclipseMars\workspace\deploy and i have to give relative path to master\gradlew.bat.

I gave like this

cd C:\EclipseMars\workspace\deploy..\master\gradlew.bat
 Its showing error system cannot find path specified.

How to give path correctly?

Comment: What is the full pathname of `gradlew.bat`?  You might need to use `…\deploy\..\master\gradlew.bat`, or you might need to use something else, depending on where the file is really located.

Comment: Yeah i missed \ after deploy..i got it:)